# How can I disable the Universal Access Settings icon?

Tags: gnome

In Gnome 3 on the top right corner I have this universal access icon with all these options which I am not intending to use in the meanwhile. How can I disable/hide the useless for me icon there?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit the file `/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js`

Comment out this line like so:

```
//'a11y': imports.ui.status.accessibility.ATIndicator,
```

[Full article here](http://conjurecode.com/disable-the-universal-access-accessibility-menu-in-gnome-3/).

Answer (score 2):

There is an extension for that called GNOME Shell noa11y, which removes the Accessibility icon from the GNOME Shell system status area.

more information [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/more-gnome-shell-extensions-mediaplayer.html).

Comment: That one didn't work for me with gnome shell 3.2.1

Comment: Installing a whole extension just to hide an icon? Definitely something Gnomish.

Answer (score 1):

In 3.5 and I believe 3.4 the function was moved to

```
/usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/sessionMode.js
```

if you comment out line 11

```
'a11y': imports.ui.status.accessibility.ATIndicator,
```

it will disable calling the accessibility icon

I also posted a solution at [Gnome Shell Remove Accessibility Icon](http://kludgeoverflow.com/blog/gnome-shell-remove-accessibility-icon/)

Comment: I'm on 3.4 and this is indeed the case.  Thanks for the tip.  Worked for me (after a restart, alt+f2, 'r').

Answer (score 1):

For GNOME 3.6 there is an extension at https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112/remove-accesibility/ that solves the problem. It worked for me in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I conform it also works with Ubuntu 21.04 and its default GNOME version.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this problem, but it appeared out of nowhere, one day. Of course, editing configuration files is doable, but not my purpose.

But apparently if you have one of the options there activated, the menu automatically appears. In my case, I had the scaling factor of the text at 1.01 (instead of 1.00), which triggered the "Large Text" configuration, which forced the icon. Simply disabling it (and thus, resetting the scaling factor to 1.00), did the trick.

So if you don't need any of the accessibility features (or they are just on by accident), disabling all of them will probably make the icon disappear.

Answer (score 1):

on GNOME Shell 3.38.2 the extension below worked for me:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2398/hide-universal-access/

Answer (score 0):

Easy, Click the control Cog at the top right (the one to the right of your name>)
Second click System Settings, from there select Universal Access, then select typing and UNSELECT "turn on accessibility features from the keyboard."

The icon should instantly disappear. HOWEVER you may need to reboot.

Comment: That does not work for me; it only shows/hides an icon in the system tray on the bottom right of the screen. Restarting gnome3 does not help (alt+f2, "r") - the icon stays

Comment: didn't work for me as well

Answer (score 0):

Not a real solution, but notable: There is [bug #640190](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=640190) in the gnome bug tracker which requested this ability. Unfortunately, it has been closed as WONTFIX.

Answer (score 0):

For 3.6 there is no solution at the moment. See https://github.com/ecoleman/noa11y-colemando.com/issues/7

Answer (score 0):

For 3.6 you can remove 'a11y', from line 99 that starts with right:

```
[ for section 'user': { in /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/sessionMode.js
```