# How to remove Universal Access from the Notification Area?

Tags: gnome, 12.10, notification, notification-area

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I disable the Universal Access Settings icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/53032/how-can-i-disable-the-universal-access-settings-icon)

I just installed 12.10 with GNOME 3.6 and in the Notification Area left to the clock there is a icon for universal access.

How is it possible to remove that notification icon?

Comment: There's a extension for remove it https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112/remove-accesibility/

Answer (score 0):

You could use Edocastillo's suggestion, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/112/remove-accesibility/, or try the [Eye! extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/502/eye/), which makes the icon into a nice eyeball that follows your mouse around.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to System Settings... > Universal Access
2. Select Typing tab
3. Uncheck 'Turn on accessibility features from the keyboard'