# GDM without Accessibility Dialog

Tags: gdm, accessibility

I would like to disable the accessibility icon on the top right corner of GDM.
I tryed insert some keys at the gconf, but thoses commands gave me **no results**:

```
gconftool --type Boolean --set /desktop/gnome/interface/accessibility false
gconftool --type Boolean --set /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_magnifier_enabled false
gconftool --type Boolean --set /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_keyboard_enabled false
gconftool --type Boolean --set /desktop/gnome/applications/at/screen_reader_enabled false
```

I found those keys on [GDM 3.14 Manual](https://help.gnome.org/admin/gdm/3.14/configuration.html.en#accessibilitygconfconfiguration).
I'm Using Ubuntu Gnome 14.10 and GDM 3.14.1.

Does anyone knows what did I do wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I disable the Universal Access Settings icon?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/53032/how-can-i-disable-the-universal-access-settings-icon)

Comment: There's quite a while that Gnome had change GDM files infrastructure, those files don't exist any more. I also checked the extension, but doesn't work. The manual says that it can be changed through the GConf.

Comment: Right, I could see js UI files in source but not in installed packages.

Answer (score 0):

`gconf` has been replaced with `dconf` long time ago. See [When to use gconf vs dconf? - around Dec 2011](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91403/when-to-use-gconf-vs-dconf)

Try:

```
dconf write /org/gnome/desktop/a11y/always-show-universal-access-status false
```

or

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.a11y always-show-universal-access-status false
```

Better to use `dconf-editor` (GUI tool) to browse all available options.