# 18.04 Remove universal access icon from top panel

Tags: command-line, icons, gui

Brand spanking noob here! XD wanting to know how to remove the universal access icon from the top bar see: [image: http://imgbox.com/2Ks8rEFG]

Tried tweaks and turning off options in the settings/universal access.

wasn't sure what the terminal cmd would be. thanks

Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS / Gnome 3.28.2

edit: previous answers included ->

Edit the file /usr/share/gnome-shell/js/ui/panel.js
Comment out this line like so:
//'a11y': imports.ui.status.accessibility.ATIndicator,

however when following this path the folder "js" (and other items onward are missing).

Comment: Please provide OS/release details.  It's best if we're told, rather than making guessed based on a picture (which can lead to further problems if we're wrong).

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Gnome 3.28.2

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/179165/197910

Comment: I only seem to have the path /usr/share/gnome-shell/ (but then no js/ui/panel.js ). I tried the other folders : extensions; modes; search-providers; theme but couldn't see a folder js. Then tried a search for "panel.js" but couldn't find it to edit.

Comment: PERFECT. Yes that did it - can't believe it didn't show up in my search!! Thanks XD